# How to create a dictionary out of a list of lists in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let's suppose I have the following list made out of lists

```
list1 = [['a','b'],['a'],['b','c'],['c','d'],['b'], ['a','d']]
```

I am wondering if there is a way to convert every element of `list1` in a dictionary where all the new dictionaries will use the same key. E.g: if `['a']`
 gets to be `{'a':1}`, and `['b']` gets to be `{'b':2}`, I would like for all keys `a` the value of `1` and for all keys `b` the value of `2`. Therefore, when creating the dictionary of `['a','b']`, I would like  to turn into `{'a':1, 'b':2}`.

What I have found so far are ways to create a dictionary out of lists of lists but using the first element as the key and the rest of the list as the value:

Please note that's not what I am interested in.
The result I would want to obtain from `list1` is something like:

```
dict_list1 = [{'a':1,'b':2}, {'a':1}, {'b':2,'c':3}, {'c':3,'d':4}, {'b':2}, {'a':1,'d':4}]
```

I am not that interested in the items being that numbers but in the numbers being the same for each different key.

Comment: `{'b':3,'c':4}` ?

Comment: My mistake, ``{'b':2,'c':4}``

Comment: c should be 3 and d should be 4 ?

Comment: @sachindubey I just add that I am not as interested in the numbers themselves but in being sure that every key in the dictionary have the same value in all the dictionaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) you can do auto mapping

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import OrderedDict

list1 = [['a','b'],['a'],['b','c'],['c','d'],['b'], ['a','d']]
# do flat list for auto index
flat_list = list(chain(*list1))
# remove duplicates
flat_list = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(flat_list))
mapping = {x:flat_list.index(x)+1 for x in set(flat_list)}

[{e: mapping[e] for e in li} for li in list1]
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to declare your mapping first:

```
mapping = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
```

Then, you can just use dict comprehension:

```
[{e: mapping[e] for e in li} for li in list1]
# [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1}, {'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4}, {'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'd': 4}]
```

Comment: You could potentially create `mapping` automatically. e.g. `mapping = {a:i for i,a in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 1)}`.

Comment: Unfortunately `mapping` assignment can only be formulated after having looked to the list content.

Answer (score 2):

Here a try with `ord()` also it will work for both capital and lower letters :

```
[{e: ord(e)%32 for e in li} for li in list1]
```